# Understanding xyplot in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I'm an R newbie and I'm trying to understand the xyplot function in lattice.

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Mean=as.vector(abc), Cycle=seq_len(nrow(abc)), Sample=rep(colnames(abc), each=nrow(abc)))
```

and I can plot it using

```
xyplot(Mean ~ Cycle, group=Sample, df, type="b", pch=20, auto.key=list(lines=TRUE, points=FALSE, columns=2), file="abc-quality")
```

My question is, what are Mean and Cycle? Looking at ?xyplot I can see that this is some kind of function and I understand they are coming from the data frame df, but I can't see them with `ls()` and `>Mean` gives `Error: object 'Mean' not found`. I tried to replicate the plot by substituting df[1] and df[2] for Mean and Cycle respectively thinking that these would be equal but that doesn't seem to be the case. Could someone explain what data types these are (objects, variables, etc) and if there is a generic way to access them (like df[1] and df[2])?

Thanks!

EDIT: xyplot works fine, I'm just trying to understand what Mean and Cycle are in terms of how they relate to df (column labels?) and if there is a way to put them in the xyplot function without referencing them by name, like df[1] instead of Mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are simply references to columns of `df`.

If you'd like access them by name without mentioning `df` every time, you could write `with(df,{ ...your code goes here... }`). The `...your code goes here...` block can access the columns as simply `Mean` and `Cycle`.

A more direct way to get to those columns is `df$Mean` and `df$Cycle`. You can also reference them by position as `df[,1]` and `df[,2]`, but I struggle to see why you would want to do that.

The reason your `xyplot` call works is it that implicitly does the equivalent of `with(df)`, where `df` is your third argument to `xyplot`. Many R functions are like this, for example `lm(y~x,obs)` would also correctly pick up columns `x` and `y` from dataframe `obs`.

Comment: Most experienced users discourage `attach()`.

Comment: I also mentioned `with()` but you forgot the obvious: the `data=` argument to `xyplot()`.  Isn't that the easiest solution?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I think you're misreading the question. The OP's code does work and already does pass `data=df` (the third argument to `xyplot`).

Comment: Thanks aix, is there a way to access the columns x y (from your example) in terms of the data frame they come from, like obs[1] for x and obs[2] for y?

Comment: @helicase: Yes, there is - please see my updated answer (`df[,1]` and `df[,2]`).

Comment: oh ok, so Mean and Cycle are simply labels for the columns, I was just accessing them incorrectly df[1] instead of df[,1]. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @helicase And you can see columns using `ls(df)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `, data=df` to your call to `xyplot()`:

```
xyplot(Mean ~ Cycle, data=df,                  # added data= argument
       group=Sample, type="b", pch=20, 
       auto.key=list(lines=TRUE, points=FALSE, columns=2), 
       file="abc-quality")
```

Alternatively, you can `with(df, ....)` and place your existing call where I left the four dots.

Comment: Thanks, xyplot seems to be working fine, I'm just confused as to what Mean and Cycle are and why I have to call them by name in the xyplot function.

Comment: You created Mean and Cycle in your first command, these are the columns of the data.frame.